# Custom UITableView Cell

Tags: objective-c, xcode, custom-controls

What is the Right Way to Implement This?

For example, say I created an XIB file with a button in it. Say a button on that custom controller get pressed, how do the program knows which "row" of the UITableView get pressed? Does each row has their own UITableViewCell Controller?

There has to be one right way to design this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the tutorial for custom cells -

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about two different controls (buttons and cells), but anyway both have a similar way to "communicate" with the controller. With the button's **tag** and the cell's **index**, you have enough to be able to manage the use of these controls.

Comment: Before I select this ans the answer. Does the IBAction thingy inform us of the index? I know that we know the tag. What about the index?

Comment: I don't think so. Anyway, if you want to use a table view, you will need to implement the **UITableViewDelegate protocol**. With the method _- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath_ you can configure what happens once a cell of the table view is selected.

Comment: So if we want to click a button on a table cell we need to select the table first?